# Function call stack overflow

Tags: common-lisp, stack-overflow, franz-lisp

I get the error message below when I run my code. The code below add the elements that are not nil.

```
(summit2 '(0 nil 1 2))

Error: Received signal number -3 (function call stack overflow (delayed response))
[condition type: ASYNCHRONOUS-OPERATING-SYSTEM-SIGNAL]
```

I have tried changing null with nil. I also tried using eq as opposed to eql.

```
(defun summit2 (lst)
    (if (eql (car lst) null)
        (summit2 (cdr lst))
      (+ (car lst) (summit2 (cdr lst)))))
```

the expected output should be 3, the sum of the elements in the list that are not nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the check for `nil` should be done by using the `NULL` function, so `(null (car lst))` in your case. Secondly, your recursion lacks the base case (the error you're getting indicates a stack overflow due to infinite recursion). Now you only distinguish between whether the next element is `nil` or non-`nil`. You need a third case to handle the empty list. This suggests the use of `COND`. You could, for example do something like:

```
(defun summit2 (lst)
  (cond 
    ((null lst)
     0)
    ((null (car lst))
     (summit2 (cdr lst)))
    (t
     (+ (car lst) (summit2 (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: Thank you. Made the changes as suggested and it now works!

Comment: You're welcome. The important bit is for you to understand *why* it works :).

Comment: @MohamedNabassoua, if that's all you might consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks

- You can spell your list `list`, there is no need to abbreviate it to `lst`.
- All branches in your code leads to a recursive call to `summit`, there is no case where you stop computing the result. This infinite computation takes up stack space, which is why it eventually stops with a stack overflow.
- Please indent your code in a conventional way (read for example [this style guide](https://lisp-lang.org/style-guide/))

Notice that the case where an element is `nil` is not much different than the case where the input list is empty. With the following code, both are handled the same way:

```
(defun sum (val)
  (if (consp val)
      (+ (sum (car val))
         (sum (cdr val)))
      (or val 0)))
```

This also means the code is able to do more than expected, i.e. you can sum numbers in a tree:

```
(sum '(0 1 2 nil 4 5 7 (1 2)))
=> 22
```

And it also works when the input is just an number:

```
(sum 5)
=> 5
```